# Copy pull request description to work item comments on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, tfs-workitem

When PR is approved, there is message "Completing Pull Request 123 and the associated work items." added to associated work item's comments area.

Is there any way how to append PR description?

I have zapier webhook attached to comments and I wont to get PR message in another app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When PR is approved, there is message "Completing Pull Request 123 and
>   the associated work items." added to associated work item's comments
>   area.

Based on this description, I guess you are attempting to append the PR description to work item comment while the `Pull Request is completing`, right?

Afraid to say that there's no such out-of-box feature can let you direct to use. But you can consider to run powershell scripts along with rest api in build pipeline to achieve such goal.

---

The logic of my suggestion is:

**Step 1**: Prepare environment.

Create one build pipeline, and make its `trigger type` as `Continues Integration`(*CI*). Only this, the pull request completing can trigger this pipeline processing, then do next job.

**Step 2**: Get the PR completing node id, then get corresponding Pull request ID by calling this [PRs query api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20query/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

For the build which run by **CI**, there has one environment variable `Build.SourceVersion` can represents the merge node id which generated by Pull request complete.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo name}/PullRequestQuery?api-version=6.0-preview.1

{
  "queries": [
    {
      "type": 1,
      "items": [
        "$(Build.SourceVersion)" // Put the $(Build.SourceVersion) value here.
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, in its response body, you will see there has one parameter `pullRequestId` which target to the Pull request this commit id associated with.

[image]

**Step 3**: [Get detailed PR `description` and `work item id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) by using the `pull request id` we get in step 2.

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo name}/pullrequests/{pull request id}?includeWorkItemRefs=true&api-version=5.1
```

Put the `pull reqeust id` we got from `step 2` into this api, then you can see the `description` contents along with the `work item id` from its response body:

[image]

**Step 4**: [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) this description contents to corresponding work item comment area.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project name}/_apis/wit/workItems/{WorkItem Id}?api-version=5.1-preview.3

[
  {
      "op": "add",
      "path": "/fields/System.History",
      "Value": $(description) // put the description here
  }
]
```

---

As I mentioned firstly, make sure this pipeline is triggered by CI. Then you will get the `description` contents be added into WIT `comment` once the Pull request is **completing**.

Comment: thnx, I'll try this

Comment: @Mengdi How would you traverse the JSON from the PullRequestQuery API to get the pullRequestId using PowerShell? Should I use regex? I tried something like $response.results[0].$(Build.SourceVersion)[0].pullRequestId but that didn't work.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО Pls use this format to print the **pullrequestId** value: `$response.results.$(Build,SourceVersion).PullRequestId`

Comment: @ΕГИІИО There's only one `results` object exists in the response body, so here you don't need use the format like this: **results[0]**

Comment: @MengdiLiang thanks for the insight. But I just found out that my issue lies elsewhere. The damned Build.SourceVersion could sometimes start with a number and then the whole dotting goes haywire in PS. I think the PSObject breaks when its property name starts with a number. But I finally managed to get to it via looping the results.PsObject.Properties.